# Are there conventions for naming 'through' models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, naming-conventions, has-many-through

Django has some very clear conventions for naming models:

- do so in the singular
- describe the object the model represents
- using capWords convention etc.

When you are using a 'through' model, to describe a many-to-many relationship however, you are no longer describing an object, but a relationship between objects.

Having googled a bit, I can't find any guidance on naming 'through' models. The example used in the django docs (`Musician` and `Band`) is named `Membership`. This is kind of perfect because membership exactly describes the relationship between the musician and the band. But in so many other cases there doesn't seem to be a word (or even phrase) to describe such a relationship.

Take for example, the other situation used in the django docs (for a 'normal' many-to-many field) of `Pizza` and `Topping`. There doesn't seem to be a good word to describe how a pizza relates to a topping; and if I therefore needed a through field to add additional information (e.g. maybe I have a primary topping and a secondary topping) I end up with a naming difficulty.

In practice there are two (maybe more, but two that I can think of) ways to procede:

1. Call the through model something along the lines of `ThingOneThingTwoRelationship` e.g. `PizzaToppingRelationship`. I guess this works, but it's kind of ugly and verbose.
2. Try and name the field after the additional info it stores, e.g. `ToppingSignificance`. Less ugly than option 1, but has other drawbacks. For one, if the model grows to contain additional information the name is no longer particularly descriptive. If we take the 'band' example from the django docs. Imagine if we started with just the `joining_date`, and we called the `Membership` model, `MemberJoingDate` as that model grew to include, `reason` and `leaving_date`, the name would no longer be apt.

### So what am I actually asking...

1. Are there any known conventions (not opinions) for naming through fields. I'm guessing there's nothing official or I would have found it on the django site, but are there any conventions that are just standards that are generally accepted by folk that have been doing this a while.
2. Failing that, are there any django style guides that discuss this (two-scoops etc. - if I have my copy available I'd look it up)
3. Failing either of the above, are there any conventions that could be borrowed from general relational database parlance.

... yes, I know - naming things is hard.

Comment: Django by default names a through model `SourceModel_m2mfield`, so for example `Pizza_toppings`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hmm... interesting. It kind of works, but I think I would find that confusing reading the code. It wouldn't be obvious to me that it was a model, even a through model. For a model, I would expect something along the lines of `PizzaToppings`. If it was a convention that I knew people would understand I'd go with it. But I'm afraid others reading my code would  follow the same train of thought that I would above and then get confused.

Comment: I can appreciate it wouldn't take much for someone to figure out what it is, but that's not the point when thinking about readability.

Comment: well to be honest, I find that name convention not very "good", but yes, that's an opinion. But if you thus *not* specify a `through` model, Django makes one itself, and you can access it through `Pizza.toppings.through` Every model has thus a `through` model, although the programmer does not per se specifies it explicitly.

Comment: I usually think about what I'm adding. That determines whether I need a through model at all and the name isn't that hard any more. Pizza's and toppings is a bad example, cause what you want to add is a property of one of the two and belongs to the model, not to both. In a hotel, a through model for a Room and Guest is a Booking and I want to add temporal information (start/end date). Usually, if it's hard to come up with a name, you may not need a through model.